# Is it possible to use multiple continue statements in for loop?

Tags: java

I am reading through a text file in this format:

```
    Quec
    23
    Pirata
    121
    Culiacan
    85
    Asi
    55
    Nomas
    0
    Quedo
    0
    Viejon
    0
STARTS AGAIN
    Quec
    48
    Pirata
    54
    Culiacan
    5
    Asi
    76
    Nomas
    2
    Quedo
    69
    Viejon
    8
```

As you can see the names are repeated twice but they are assigned different values once the list starts again. I have to apply some logic to the list. I currently have this for loop

```
for(int i =0;i<100;i++)
{
    //nameArray stores the names found in text file 
    if(nameArray[i].equals("Quec")) //Repeat this for every name
          //DO LOGIC
}
```

I basically need to do the logic with the first set of data and repeat the same logic with the second set of data. Is is possible to use multiple continue statements in order to achieve this? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple continue statements in for loop? Yes. Is there another way to do it? Yes. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you approach the problem with something like this?

```
private void processFile(Scanner in, int groups) {
    for (int groupId=0; groupId<groups; group++) {
        processGroup(in, groupId);
    }
}

private void processGroup(Scanner in, int groupId) {
    for (int groupRow=0; groupRow<FIELDS_PER_GROUP; groupRow++) {
        String name=in.next();
        int value=in.nextInt();
        processEntry(name, value, group);
    }
}

private void processEntry(String name, int value, int group) {
    // do some logic
}
```